# SQL query to save row value into php variable

Tags: php, html, sql, variables

I see several questions relating to my problem, but I'm very new to programming and cant figure out half the responses. Below is the only thing I have gotten working for getting data out of my table, it is however doing way more than I need it to, and still giving me an undesired result.

I simply want to take the string from the first row of my table and save into a php variable called `$news1`.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PW");

if(!$connection)
{
    die("<p>no connection to database</p>");   
}

if(!mysql_select_db("akron11_db", $connection))
{
    die("<p>Kunne ikke finde databasen</p>");
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT news1 FROM TurenTilDannmark", $connection);   

if(!$result)
{
    die("<p>Efterspørgslen slog fejl " . mysql_error() . "</p>");   
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($item = 0; $item < $rows; $item++)
{
    echo "<li>" . mysql_result($result, $item) . "</li>";  
} 

echo "</p>";
```

Comment: "an undesiered result." Can you be a bit more specific please? What is the result you get, and what were you hoping for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use limit to fetch just one result:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT news1 FROM TurenTilDannmark LIMIT 1', $connection);
```

Then you you can use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['news1']; // ta-da!
```

Or [mysql_result](http://php.net/mysql_result):

```
$news1 = mysql_result($result, 0); // 0 is the index of the field, not the row
echo $news1;
```

Comment: Thanks middus, that was so simple! You guys rock.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FIRST(news1) FROM TurenTilDannmark", $connection);
```

`FIRST()` is equivalent to `LIMIT 1`.

That should give you only one row when you do next:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: No error, but echoing the result gives gives no output.
    $news1 = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 news1 FROM TurenTilDannmark",     $connection);
    echo $news1;

Comment: @user1091537: It's not `$result` that you need to echo. You need to do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` then `echo $row['news1'];` just like *middus* wrote in his answer.

Comment: Sorry site moved too fast for me xD it works now! Thanks all.